# Huggingface Pipeline for Question And Answering

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm trying out the QnA model (DistilBertForQuestionAnswering -'distilbert-base-uncased') by using HuggingFace pipeline. I saved the model in a local location using 'save_pretrained'. Then I reloaded the model later using 'from_pretrained'. However, the model performs differently when loaded from the local location. There seems to be something amiss in the way I am loading the saved models.

```
    from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, DistilBertForQuestionAnswering
    path_d  = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Pipeline/distilbert'
    #  1 - save model 
    model_n = DistilBertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
    model_n.save_pretrained(path_d)
    #2 - save tokenizer 
    tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
    tokenizer.save_pretrained(path_d) 
    
    #load the saved model in another file. 
    model_d = DistilBertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(path_d)       
    #load tokenizer 
    tokenizer_d = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_d)
    
    context = 'The earliest reports of a coronavirus infection in animals occurred in the late 1920s, when an acute respiratory infection of domesticated chickens emerged in North America. Arthur
Schalk and M.C. Hawn in 1931 made the first detailed report which described a new respiratory infection of chickens in North Dakota. The infection of new-born chicks was characterized by
gasping and listlessness with high mortality rates of 40–90%. Leland David Bushnell and Carl Alfred Brandly isolated the virus that caused the infection in 1933. The virus was then known
as infectious bronchitis virus (IBV). Charles D. Hudson and Fred Robert Beaudette cultivated the virus for the first time in 1937. The specimen came to be known as the Beaudette strain.
In the late 1940s, two more animal coronaviruses, JHM that causes brain disease (murine encephalitis) and mouse hepatitis virus (MHV) that causes hepatitis in mice were discovered. It
was not realized at the time that these three different viruses were related.'
   # from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus 
    question = 'What is MHV?'
    
    from transformers import pipeline
    # using saved model 
    sec_layer = pipeline('question-answering', model= model_d, tokenizer = tokenizer_d )
    output = sec_layer(question = question, context  =context )
    print(output)  
    # {'score': 5.989291094010696e-05, 'start': 662, 'end': 685, 'answer': 'the first time in 1937.'}
    
    #  here the model is loaded again and the answer is different ,and is the correct answer
    
    sec_layer = pipeline('question-answering') 
    out = sec_layer(question = question, context  =context ,model= model_d, tokenizer = tokenizer_d )
    print(out) 
    #{'score': 0.837104082107544, 'start': 847, 'end': 868, 'answer': 'mouse hepatitis virus'}
```

Can someone please guide me here to understand what I have done wrong in saving and reloading the model?

Comment: `sec_layer = pipeline('question-answering') ` this will load the default model `distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad` and not your stored model.

Comment: Thank you . That helped. I changed my saved model to distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad.